# Node-sass doesn't pipe in npm scripts

Tags: pipe, command-line-interface, node-sass, npm-scripts

I'm using node-sass to compile my scss files to css and then pipe the result to autoprefixer. However, I've eventually found out that node-sass is streaming nothing to stdout when I try to pipe its output, but if and only if I do it via npm scripts. 
 Here some examples:

- #### Pipe with npm

  Npm script: `"build:css": "node-sass src/style.scss | echo > dist/style.css"` 
  style.css: `ECHO is on.` **doesn't work as expected**
- #### Pipe with powershell

  Powershell: `node ./bin/node-sass test/fixtures/compressed/index.scss | echo > style.css` 
  style.css: `#navbar { [...]`**works as expected**
- #### Append with npm

  Npm script `"build:css": "node-sass src/style.scss > dist/style.css"`

   style.css: `#navbar { [...]`**works as expected**

What am I doing wrong? 

 Here some platform specs

- NPM version (`npm -v`): 3.10.3
- Node version (`node -v`): v6.3.0
- Node Process (`node -p process.versions`): v6.3.0
- Node Platform (`node -p process.platform`): win32
- Node architecture (`node -p process.arch`): x64
- node-sass version (`node -p "require('node-sass').info"`):
  node-sass       4.5.3   (Wrapper)       [JavaScript] 
  libsass         3.5.0.beta.2    (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
- npm node-sass versions (`npm ls node-sass`): `-- node-sass@4.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```json
"build:css": "node-sass --include-path scss src/style.scss dist/style.css"
```

Comment: Works like a charm IF I don't pipe (something like `node-sass --include-path src src/style.scss | echo > dist/dist.css`), which is what I'm trying to achieve to avoid continuous writes and reads of files. I've also taken a look at node-sass source code, and it seems like it should be able to pipe the output...